# Как появился новый метод при использовании module.export

Tags: node.js

Возник вопрос. Писал для поля scheme(Mongo DB) необходимые параметры, затем с помощью отправки модуля:

```
module.exports = model('Todo', schema);
```

Экспортировал его, в другом файле получил

```
const Todo = require('../models/Todo')
```

И у меня у Todo появился метод find(или любые другие). Но при этом у scheme никаких таких методов не было, как так вышло, что мы просто экспортировали переменную, а у нее появились новые методы?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в `model` это функция которая внутри себя делать нужную вам модель Todo и так же добавляет методы для работы с базой.